# Calculate the shape in fully connected layer after cnn

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to learn PyTorch. But I am really confused about the shape in a fully connected layer after convolution and max pooling.

**Case 1.** How we calculate the number 5408 in `nn.Linear`
I think 5408 = 32 * m * m, where 32 comes from the `nn.Conv2d(3, **32**, kernel_size=7, stride=2)`, but then m would equals 13. However, where is the 13 comes from?

```
simple_model = nn.Sequential(
                nn.Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size=7, stride=2),
                nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
                Flatten(), # see above for explanation
                nn.Linear(5408, 10), # affine layer
              )
```

**Case 2** How we get the number 4*4 in `fc = nn.Linear(64*4*4, 10)`, the same problem in case 1. I don't know where the number 4 comes from...

```
# (conv -> batchnorm -> relu -> maxpool) * 3 -> fc

layer1 = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Conv2d(3, 16, kernel_size = 5, padding = 2),
    nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.MaxPool2d(2)
)
layer2 = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size = 3, padding = 1),
    nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.MaxPool2d(2)  
)
layer3 = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size = 3, padding = 1),
    nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
    nn.ReLU(),
    nn.MaxPool2d(2)  
)
fc = nn.Linear(64*4*4, 10)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good primer (specifically the summary) on calculating these sorts of things: 
 http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/

[image: Calculations for Height and Width after applying a convolution]

Where

- W = Input width
- Fw = Receptive field (kernel) width
- P = Padding
- Sw = Stride along width

You haven't mentioned your input width/height, but I'm assuming they're `28x28` MNIST images.

In that case we have:

- W = `28`
- Fw = `7`
- P = `2`
- Sw = `2`

Plugging those numbers into the above equation will give you `13.5` which is awkward because it's not an integer. In the case of PyTorch it seems to *round it down* to 13. (It's actually proven kind of hard to find any documentation of this fact other than [this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-calculate-the-output-size-after-conv2d-in-pytorch/20405) forum post)

**Edit:** The actual implementation for cuDNN is here: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/fdab1cf0d485820907d7541266d69b70e1d3d16b/aten/src/ATen/native/cudnn/Conv.cpp#L157-L158

For your second case, it seems like your inputs are not `28x28` and must be `32x32`. The convolutions don't shrink the height and width (you can plug the numbers in yourself and check). However the `MaxPool2d(2)` layer shrinks the height and width  by half after each convolution. So you go from:

`32x32`->`16x16`->`8x8`-> `4x4`